# Speech Framework API locally without network connection

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, ios10, siri, dictation

I'm trying to figure it out. Dictation on some iOS devices seems to work without inet connection at all. So the Microphone icon is available on iOS Keyboard even when I have disabled Mobile Data and Wifi.

On some devices Settings -> General -> Keyboards
Look like this:

[image]

And on some devices it looks like this:

[image]

Both devices uses the iOS 10.2.1 version. The first screen is coming from iPhone 6s+ and second is from iPhone 6. Does somebody know on which devices this is supported? Is there any official Apple information about this topic. My goal is to make it work without inet connection and use Speech Framework without inet connection to recognize speech.